# Weird behavior surfaceView within TableLayout

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-tablelayout

I'm working on a sofware who's diplaying brain's maps. I have several maps which are refreshed at each iteration of time. I would like to diplay these map in a zoomable table layout, so I use the class  `AwesomeTableLayout.java` (just a basic tableLayout to start):

```
public class AwesomeTableLayout extends TableLayout{

    public AwesomeTableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public AwesomeTableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Each map are diplayed using a SurfaceView called MapView :

```
public class MapView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
```

I want to add these map progammatically, then the user can remove/add different map (input, memory, focus etc) .

So in my `MainActivity` I do :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                Resources r = getResources();
        XmlResourceParser parser = r.getXml(R.layout.activity_main);
        AttributeSet as = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        mMapView = new MapView(context, as);
        mMapView2 = new MapView(context, as);

        AwesomeTableLayout tl = (AwesomeTableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.addView(new AddMapOrStatsView(context, 0, 0));
        tr.addView(mMapView2);
        tr.addView(mMapView);
        tr.addView(new AddMapOrStatsView(context, 0, 1));
        tr.addView(new AddMapOrStatsView(context, 0, 2));
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

The class `AddMapOrStatsView` is just a kind of "add" image to add a new map on the table (the image is the alien of android) :

```
public class AddMapOrStatsView extends ImageView{

    public AddMapOrStatsView(Context context,final int ligne,final int colonne) {
        super(context);
        /* image utilisée */
        setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Un click simple sur l' AddMapOrStatsView("+ligne+","+colonne+") a été effectué !");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `activity_main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.main.gui.AwesomeTableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <!-- 2 columns -->

<!--     <TableRow -->
<!--         android:id="@+id/tableRow1" -->
<!--         android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
<!--         android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!--         android:padding="5dip" > -->

<!--         <TextView -->
<!--             android:id="@+id/textView1" -->
<!--             android:text="Column 1" -->
<!--             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> -->

<!--         <Button -->
<!--             android:id="@+id/button1" -->
<!--             android:text="Column 2" /> -->

<!--         <Button -->
<!--             android:id="@+id/buttonxx" -->
<!--             android:text="Column 3" /> -->
<!--     </TableRow> -->

</com.main.gui.AwesomeTableLayout>
```

Now, here the problem. If I run the application with the previous code I see this :

[image: code wanted]

as you can see ,I only see the 3 views AddMapOrStatView.

If I uncomment the xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.main.gui.AwesomeTableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <!-- 2 columns -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />

<!--         <Button -->
<!--             android:id="@+id/buttonxx" -->
<!--             android:text="Column 3" /> -->
    </TableRow>

</com.main.gui.AwesomeTableLayout>
```

I see this :

[image: eee]

If I click on play (ie I draw the two surfaceView) I see this :

[image: zzzz]

Finally, I uncomment my xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.main.gui.AwesomeTableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <!-- 2 columns -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonxx"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

</com.main.gui.AwesomeTableLayout>
```

I see this :

[image]

THen when I draw the two surface view , I see this :

[image]

The thing is, I just want to see the 3 pictures of the android and the two map. Why the hell should I add some other stuff in the tableLayout's row to see my surface view ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the size of the surfaceView's holder like this :

```
holder.setFixedSize(60, 60);
```

It's working now !